# Оптимальный парсинг строки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

Имеется множество строк, состоящие из разного количества подстрок.
Все подстроки разделены пробелами.
Первая подстрока **всегда** и начинается с '>' и далее там могут идти ещё несколько символов.
Все остальные, кроме последней, идут в квадратных скобках, внутри которых имеются нужные данные в виде
"[key=value]", **value** может содержать пробелы. Эти подстроки могут меняться местами.
Последняя подстрока это неразрывный набор латиницы верхнего регистра.

Нужно выделить из этого набора несколько нужных подстрок и засунуть в объект класса

Пример строк:

```
>dfg|sf_sdfg0.1 [gene=aziz] [musor1=otyuj] [musor2=fsdgk] [protein=73545] KHGDBSS
>vgv|kjs_u9.5_W [protein=pivo vkusno] [musor3=dsfg] [gene=mama] LJDFSGJKHKGJGKB
```

Нужно вытащить по ключу `gene=`, `protein=` и последнюю строку
На выходе должен получится массив строк :

```
{"aziz", "73545", "KHGDBSS"}
{"mama", "pivo vkusno", "LJDFSGJKHKGJGKB"}
```

Если строка не будет иметь ключа `gene=` - её нужно пропустить.

P.S. Сейчас имеется рабочий вариант, на куче проверок вхождения строк и вытаскивания индексов. Работает медленно, боюсь для ускорения нужны будут 'Регулярные выражения', с которыми я пока не дружу, или ещё какие шарповые уловки, о которых я даже не догадываюсь.

U.D.P. забыл добавить что строка Атрибутов всегда начинается с новой строчки и  пишется в одну строку, а последняя часть с латиницей в верхнем регистре всегда начинается со следующей строки делится на блоки по 70 символов.

```cs
>idf|sdf [attr1=x] [attr2=y] [attr3=z]
DFG..DFF // 70 символов
DRF..RGE // 70 символов
WEL..TRT // 70 символов
RRG // Остаток переноса
```

Comment: @aepot мне лично все понятно из данного примера. Из каждой строки нужно вытягивать конкретные атрибуты и последнюю строку (code), разделенную пробелом, в итоге ожидаемый результат должен быть: `{geneAttr, proteinAttr, lastCode}`

Comment: Каковы объёмы данных? Вас беспокоит скорость, значит можно предположить, что данных много (мегабайты? гигабайты?) В каком виде приходят данные, откуда они читаются: из файла, потока?.. Используется .net core, значит доступны спаны и многие другие фичи современных версий языка и платформы. Если заморочиться, то можно избавиться от лишних аллокаций памяти и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , Объёмы неизвестны до конца, руководитель говорит что есть текстовики и в 200+мб. Тестовые файлы выданные мне содержат 50к - 150к строк. Решение предложенное _aepot_ вполне устраивает. Хотя, конечно, от альтернативных вариантов в качестве обучения не отказываюсь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько это будет быстрее работать, чем ваше то, чего я не видел, но проверок явно не куча.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = ">dfg|sf_sdfg0.1 [gene=aziz] [musor1=otyuj] [musor2=fsdgk] [protein=73545] KHGDBSS\r\n>vgv|kjs_u9.5_W [protein=pivo vkusno] [musor3=dsfg] [gene=mama] LJDFSGJKHKGJGKB";
    string[] include = new string[] { "gene", "protein" };
    char[] braces = "[]".ToCharArray();

    foreach (string line in text.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        var tokens = line.Split(braces).Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => x.Length > 0);
        string[] values = new string[include.Length + 1];

        foreach (string token in tokens)
        {
            string[] pair = token.Split("=");
            if (pair.Length == 2)
            {
                int index = Array.IndexOf(include, pair[0]);
                if (index >= 0)
                    values[index] = pair[1];
            }
        }
        values[^1] = tokens.Last();

        Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(", ", values.Select(x => $"\"{x}\"")) + "}");
    }
}
```

```
{"aziz", "73545", "KHGDBSS"}
{"mama", "pivo vkusno", "LJDFSGJKHKGJGKB"}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения - утром ответ не дал. Решение шикарное, спасибо большое. 150к строк (по 
ощущению) парсит за пару секунд. Кода меньше, чем у меня получилось, что тоже не может не радовать. 
Немного изменил, ибо забыл упомянуть что последний код делится на строчки по 70 символов + добавил пропуски не получившихся элементов. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @YoungSideways ну это определенно можно еще ускорить, раз в 10 минимум, но без реальных данных и полных требований к решению сложновато что-либо придумать.